# Trying to test the Significance of the Seattle Seahawks Home Field Advantage

Tags: least-squares, games

Basically I have an interest in sports and as part of that do a Microsoft Excel based version of Kenneth Massey 1997 thesis (http://masseyratings.com/theory/massey97.pdf) method of ranking sports teams, that also allows for a Home Field Advantage (HFA) rating (so I have Solver within Excel solve the least squares method that I have set up based on game results to derive a best fit for the means or ratings for the teams and a common Home Field Advantage).

Due to a post on a forum elsewhere, I decided that I wanted to try and put a number on the Seattle Seahawks (NFL) team’s Home Field Advantage (HFA), which allegedly is higher than the league average. Where as my model usually allows for all of the seasons games to solve the least squares problem (to develop an accurate rating), I took data over the past 6 seasons, kept my end of season ratings constant from each of those seasons (derived on results from over 250 games - 16 games for each team) and got Excel to solve the individual Home Field Advantages based on just each of the teams home games (8 per season). The individual HFA's then averaged out to the league average solved by my original model. So effectively I fitted my problem to the model (I think?). I used the Swinburne University of Technology by Paper by Stephen Clarke into “Home Field Advantage in the Australian Football League” (http://researchbank.swinburne.edu.au/vital/access/manager/Repository/swin:1561?exact=creator%3A%22Clarke%2C+Stephen+R.%22) as a basis for the concept and in particular it’s reference to Harville, D. A., and Smith, M. H. (1994). “The home-court advantage: How large is it, and does it vary from team to team?” The American Statistician, 48, 22-28.

In short taking data over 6 seasons (2007/2008 – through to 2012/2013), I have found 4 teams that are over two points different to the league average (and 28 that were within 2 points which I didn’t think was a big enough difference) and these teams seem to on average be in either the top 10 or bottom 10 of Home Field Advantages;

At the top;

Seattle Seahawks – average HFA rank 7th – average difference to league average HFA of 2.58: +3.47 points (e.g. Seattle’s HFA = 6.05)
Baltimore Ravens – average HFA rank 9th – average difference to league average HFA: +2.64 points

And at the bottom;

Carolina Panthers – average HFA 23rd – average difference to league average HFA: -2.11 points
Miami Dolphins – average HFA 24th – average difference league average HFA: -2.61points (so on average HFA is marginally negative and the only team that this would affect).

My query is; is there a way to test the significance of the 3.47 points above the league average value of the Seattle Seahawks individual HFA? Is it significant? Is the data set of games big enough (6 seasons – 48 games per team)? Am I right to disregard anything below 2 points off of the average as not being significant enough (that it might just be caused by a one season blip)? I am also not looking for the causation of the HFA (which I am expecting to be a combination of familiarity as the stadium has been open only ten years and travel as Seattle is the most isolated of NFL teams). I just want to prove that it is significant (and then I can go after the causes).

I don’t have a great maths background (just an interest in sports) so I would be grateful for any advice as I think being consistently 3 points above the league average must be a significant advantage.

Thanks,

Comment: I went away and tried to take the z-score approach with this but am not sure that I have understood the approach or whether it is valid e.g. (avg.diff seattle - avg.diff NFL)/standard deviation of differences to league average HFA. In the case of Seattle: (3.47-0)/1.32 = approx 2.64. On the basis that this is above 2.0 can I treat it as significant over 6 years? Incidentally the only other teams that were close to 2, were Baltimore (at virtually exactly 2.0) and Miami (at -1.98). 5 other teams had a 1 or -1 value. Everything else was between 1 and -1.